# Interesting properties of maps whose natural representation is unitary?

Tags: quantum-operation, resource-request, linear-algebra

Let $\rho \in L(\mathcal{X})$ be a state in the space of linear operators acting on some complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{X}$. I'm interested in linear maps $\Phi: L(\mathcal{X}) \rightarrow L(\mathcal{X})$ whose *natural representation is unitary*, i.e. letting $U(\mathcal{Y})$ denote the set of unitaries acting on $\mathcal{Y}$ there is some $K(\Phi) \in U(\mathcal{X} \otimes \mathcal{X})$ such that

$$
\text{Vec}\left({\Phi(\rho)} \right) = K(\Phi) \text{Vec}(\rho)
$$

What conditions are necessary/sufficient for $\Phi$ to be a channel (completely postive, trace-preserving)?

I would also appreciate references discussing this kind of map, if such a thing exists.